# Avoid duplicates of a column using Not exists SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

How to avoid duplicates of a column using distinct?

I want to get the passports from the table RELATION that doesn't exist to the table PERSON. This it works using the NOT EXISTS.

But I also want to print the relID  (it doesn't matter which from each passport).

these are my tables:

RELATION

```
relID   passport  date
1       400000V   21/07/2019
2       400000V   31/02/2019
3       400000V   31/07/2011
4       342342X   31/12/2012
5       342342X   11/10/2011
6       823972O   31/07/2019
```

Table PERSON:

```
id   passport
1    342342X  
2    3333333T
3    1111111W
```

This is the result I want.

```
relID   passport
1       400000V     
6       823972O
```

Thats my query:

```
select 
     distinct passport
from RELATION
where not exists(select 1 from PERSON where PERSON.passport= RELATION.passport)
```

If I add the column relID to the select i got duplicates values from passport.

I only want to get unique PASSPORT with one of their relID  .

Answer (score 1):

Just use aggregation:

```
select max(relid), passport
from relation
group by passport;
```

I don't understand what the `person` table has to do with the question.

Comment: Because I only want the get the passports that doesn't appear to the table PERSON. For that I need to use a NOT EXISTS.

Answer (score 1):

Use an OUTER JOIN, checking to see if the PASSPORT field in the joined table is NULL, which indicates that the PASSPORT value from RELATION doesn't exist in PERSON:

```
SELECT r.PASSPORT, MIN(r.RELID)
  FROM RELATION r
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PERSON p
    ON p.PASSPORT = r.PASSPORT
  WHERE p.PASSPORT IS NULL
  GROUP BY r.PASSPORT
  ORDER BY r.PASSPORT
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d96b72ce526ec9167f5d805895caa40d)

Answer (score 0):

use min ()

```
select min(relID),passport from table group by passport
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding group by clause should help :-

`select min(relID), passport
    from RELATION
    where not exists(select 1 from PERSON where PERSON.passport= RELATION.passport)
    group by passport;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use NOT EXISTS twice, for the table PERSON and the table RELATION:

```
select r.relid, r.passport
from RELATION r
where 
  not exists (
    select 1 from PERSON 
    where passport = r.passport
  ) and
  not exists (
    select 1 from RELATION 
    where passport = r.passport and "date" > r."date"
  )
```

if the date is unique for each passport.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0fd6e20e751e0bdecd024af16139b8ed).
Results:

```
> RELID | PASSPORT
> ----: | :-------
>     1 | 400000V 
>     6 | 823972O
```